# Python 3 Schedule runs at anytime

Tags: python, cron, scheduled-tasks, schedule

I am currently writing a Python program that should start several tasks. For the time management I have installed the library Schedule. Unfortunately the scheduler executes my function every time, although it does not have the correct time. It doesn't matter if the time is in the past or in the future, the function is always executed.

```
import time
from datetime import date
import schedule


class trader():
  def __init__(self):
      pass

  def scheduler(self, x, y, z):

    
    #schedule.every().monday.at("23:10").tag().do(self.daily(x, y, z))
    schedule.every().day.at("22:10").do(self.daily(x, y, z))

    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)

  def daily(self, x, y, z):
    
    print("running")

    
    return
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`Job.do()` method](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#schedule.Job.do) expects a function object, but you are calling a function and passing the result to `.do()`

There is an [FAQ on schedule's documentation website](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#how-can-i-pass-arguments-to-the-job-function) that explains how to pass arguments to a scheduled function.

```
def my_job():
    # This job will execute every 5 to 10 seconds.
    print('Foo')

schedule.every(5).to(10).seconds.do(my_job)
```

The OP's code can be changed to

```
schedule.every().day.at("22:10").do(self.daily, x, y, z)
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, *facepalm to myself*